# Game crashes when loading vault

Tags: fallout-shelter

I seem to be experiencing a crash whenever I try to load my saved vault.  I can get to the loading screen, and it spins for a while; but I always end up with a black screen and then the app closes.

I've tried removing the app from running in the background; and did a power off/on of my device but to no avail.

Is there any way around this; or am I stuck waiting for a patch?

**Edit:**  I'm on an iPod Touch 5th Generation / iOS 8.3

**Edit #2:**  As far as I can tell; this is sporadic.  Sometimes it'll let me back in; other times not

Comment: What device are you encountering this issue on?

Comment: Did you try to reinstall the game? I think the save games will be there even on reinstall if you decide not to remove all of it.

Comment: i get this issue on an ipad mini as well

Comment: I ran into this problem as well. In a final act I upgraded the iOS version to 8.3.5 and that got my fault loading again as well as just overall the app running insanely better. Most of the stability issues I had have vanished. I unfortunately do not remember which version of the iPad I have.. except that it is heavy so I am not sure if it applies in this situation (nor can I get it to tell me any more than 8.3 for the version)

Comment: Same here - for me it's 100% of the time too. iOS 8.3, iPhone 5s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that your device isn't supported at all.

> Devices with 512 MB of RAM are not supported. This includes the iPhone 4s, iPod Touch Gen 5, iPad 2, iPad Mini Gen 1.

Source: http://help.bethsoft.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/29954

Altough, based on user reviews, it seems to have problems with other devices as well.

I belive your best bet is to hope that there will be an update that will make the game less memory consuming and/or more stable.

**Update:** A new patch, 1.0.3 came out July 10th. This may help if you have a supported device. I've found the game much more stable after the patch.